# Installing Ubuntu on ASUS Vivotab tf600t Tegr3 32 bit ARM processor

Tags: software-installation, asus, tablet

I have a ASUS Vivotab tf600t Tegr3 32 bit ARM processor and I am wanting to put Ubuntu on it and am not having luck with any of the information I have found on it but it is out dated I was wondering if anyone could tell me if it's even a possibility.

Comment: It's very possible to install Ubuntu on all the modern and no so modern PC's.  If you edit your question and add the steps you have performed and the errors you're getting, or specifically where you're stuck we would be able to see what's going wrong and how to correct it.  Basically you boot the live media and follow the installation prompts the same way you would if you were installing Windows.  I don't know specifically your Tegr3 32 bit ARM processor, but I'm sure you'll have to burn a 32 bit version of the OS for your installation.

Comment: ARM devices aren't installed as regular desktops or notebooks (X86, X86_64). There were attempts to run Ubuntu Touch in such devices but I'm afraid not much successful. And there's this https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra-archive , without desktop environment, but *ubuntu-desktop* can be installed according to Phoronix.

Comment: I've made a live USB of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 and tried to recovery boot from a media drive but it never reads anything from the USB. I'm pretty sure the problem I am running into is it has Secure Boot enabled on it and I can't find a way of disabling it.